# Why don't my installed C++ libraries on vs code run on files apart from main.cpp?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

I installed the opencv library on vs code and tried to create a test.cpp file to practice on but it shows an error reading "cannot open opencv2/core.hpp"

I tried to include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp> but it says "cannot open opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp" and does similar things for any other opencv2 file. The library only runs on main.cpp without any errors. I installed Eigen too and it has the same problem.
I'm new to this so I have no idea where to start or what to do.

c_cpp_properties.json:
{

```
"configurations": [

    {

        "name": "Win32",

        "includePath": [

            "${workspaceFolder}/**",

            "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-windows/include",

            "${vcpkgRoot}/x86-windows/include",

            "C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/vcpkg-master/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/include/eigen3",

            "C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/vcpkg-master/vcpkg-master/installed/x64-windows/include/Eigen"

        ],

        "defines": [

            "_DEBUG",

            "UNICODE",

            "_UNICODE"

        ],

        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",

        "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",

        "cStandard": "c17",

        "cppStandard": "c++17",

        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x86",

        "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",

        "forcedInclude": []

    }

],

"version": 4
```

}

tasks.json:

{

```
"tasks": [

    {

        "type": "cppbuild",

        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",

        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",

        "args": [

            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",

            "-g",

            "${file}",

            "-o",

            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",

            "-I",

            "C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/eigen-3.4.0/",

            "C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/eigen-3.4.0/eigen-3.4.0/Eigen/src"

        ],

        "options": {

            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"

        },

        "problemMatcher": [

            "$gcc"

        ],

        "group": {

            "kind": "build",

            "isDefault": true

        },

        "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."

    }

],

"version": "2.0.0"
```

}

settings.json:

```
    {
        "configurations": [

          {

            "name": "x64-Debug",

            "generator": "Ninja",

            "configurationType": "Debug",

            "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x64_x64" ],

            "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",

            "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",

            "cmakeCommandArgs": "",

            "buildCommandArgs": "",

            "ctestCommandArgs": "",

            "cmakeToolchain": "C:/Users/ashwi/Downloads/vcpkg-master/vcpkg-master/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

          }

        ],

        "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "enabled"

      }
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0) 
project (opencv VERSION 0.1.0)
include(CTest) 
enable_testing()
add_executable(opencv main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)


find_package(OpenCV CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(opencv PRIVATE opencv_ml opencv_dnn opencv_core opencv_flann)


find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(opencv PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)

add_custom_target(run
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_NAME}
    DEPENDS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_PROJECT_DIR}
)
```

Comment: the error "it shows" is from your IDE, what happens when you actually try to compile? Whats the compilers output?

Comment: tst.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: pleae concentrate on one issue not all at the same time. In your question you write about opencv, now its about eigen

Comment: That was a mistake sorry

Comment: It seems that you mixed up a few things. Your `tasks.json` defines a task that will build the current file and does add the path to `eigen` as include directory. Your `CMakeLists.txt` uses the project name `opencv` (would suggest changing it to not confuse yourself and others) and does not link to `OpenCV2`. Can you please clarify how you compile the project?

Comment: Do you have the CMakeTools extension enabled?

Comment: @Zaiborg I debug it using CMake, because when I run it normally on the g++ compiler it results in a "No such file or directory" error, but runs perfectly if I debug it.

Comment: @dreschermj Yes, I have CMakeTools enabled and everything else and it runs properly on main.cpp, but it does not on any other file I create.